# In and Out in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

If I enter "01" it will output "IN" and if I input "01" again it will out but the problem is I need to OUT the first number I enter before I can IN another number. Can someone help me????

```
class Program
{

    static string [] num = {"01","02","03"};
    static string en;
    static string en1;
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
            {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Enter your code: ");
        en = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            if (en == num[i])
            {
                Console.Write("In");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Enter your code: ");
                en1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (en1 == en)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Out");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Main();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not very clear, can you please rephrase what are you expecting from your code?

Comment: hey Carl, follow your lines of code carefully you will see you read in a code,  you then repeatedly ask if the number they typed was one of the 3 you put in an array called num.  If it was, you ask them to enter "In" as en1, but if that doesnt equal the code took then it does nothing with it.. Is this really what you wanted?

Comment: As the others have stated, if you could clarify what you are trying to do, one of us would love to help.

Comment: You probably don't want to have a recursive function - the call to Main is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to keep it simple to follow, if you're confused by any part please ask

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> num =  new List<string> (){ "01", "02", "03" }; 
    static string en;
    static string en1;
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true) {

            Console.Write("Enter your code: ");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(en)) { //check en isn't set yet
                en = Console.ReadLine(); // set en 
                if (num.Contains(en)){ // if en exists in the num list proceed
                    Console.WriteLine("IN");
                } else {
                    en = null; //if it doesn't null it and start again
                }
            } else {
                en1 = Console.ReadLine(); //read in the value to compare
                if (en == en1) { //compare the original input to this
                    en = null; //if they're the same, null the original 
                    Console.WriteLine("OUT"); 
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```